# R Custom Max Function

Tags: r, max

```
data=data.frame("person"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                "score"=c(1,2,3,2,2,1,2,3,2,3,1,4,1,4,3),
                "WANT"=c(1,2,3,3,2,1,2,3,2,3,3,4,1,4,NA))
```

For each person we track their scores until they reach "proficient" (3) or excellence (4). If a person scores excellence (4) then that value is kept and the persons next score is removed (see person 4; instead of NA would just want to remove that row however). If a person scores proficient (3) that value is carried forward UNLESS they score 4 which would replace the score of 3. Otherwise the values stay how they are. I tried cummax func but not sure how to apply such a rule.

It is my attempt below

```
data$want = ave(data$score, data$person, FUN = function(x) cummax(replace(x, is.na(x), -1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom function with the rules you specified and apply it on every person in a group by as follows,

```
library(dplyr)

count_3_4 <- function(vec){
  max = 0
  for(i in seq_along(vec)){
    if(vec[i] > max){
      max = vec[i]
      if(max == 3 || max == 4){
        vec[i] = max
      }
    }else if(max == 4 && vec[i] < max){
      vec[i] = NA
    }else{
      if(max == 3 || max == 4){
        vec[i] = max
      }
    }
  }
  return(vec)
}

data=data.frame("person"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                "score"=c(1,2,3,2,2,1,2,3,2,3,1,4,1,4,3),
                "WANT"=c(1,2,3,3,2,1,2,3,2,3,3,4,1,4,NA))

data%>%
  group_by(person)%>%
  mutate(TestVal = count_3_4(score)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: thanks so much, is there a short or more simpler approach? i am not accustomed yet to the function writing of that magnitude.

Comment: thanks so much but this doesn't  match intended output.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `cummax` for score higher than 3 or more or keep the `score` as it is. To get `NA`s after first 4 we can `replace` the `duplicated` 4 values as `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
    mutate(WANT2 = ifelse(score >= 3 | (row_number() >= which.max(score == 3)), 
                   cummax(score), score), 
            WANT2 = replace(WANT2, duplicated(WANT2 == 4) & WANT2 == 4, NA))


#   person score  WANT WANT2
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      1     1     1     1
# 2      1     2     2     2
# 3      1     3     3     3
# 4      1     2     3     3
# 5      2     2     2     2
# 6      2     1     1     1
# 7      2     2     2     2
# 8      2     3     3     3
# 9      3     2     2     2
#10      3     3     3     3
#11      3     1     3     3
#12      3     4     4     4
#13      4     1     1     1
#14      4     4     4     4
#15      4     3    NA    NA
```

Comment: person 1 row 4 is 2 but should be 3

Comment: hi it looks like you deleted an edit, and i am just wondering if you could maybe modify the code you shared thank you so much

Comment: @bvowe Sorry, I added an extra condition to check. Can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by 'person', specify the `i` to select rows where 'score' is greater than or equal to 3, get the `cummax` of 'score' and assign it to 'WANT2', replace the `NA` elements with the 'score' value (`pmax`), set the duplicated '4' values to `NA` for each 'person'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[score >=3,  WANT2 := cummax(score), person
     ][, WANT2 := pmax(score, WANT2, na.rm = TRUE), person]
i1 <- data[WANT2 == 4, .I[duplicated(WANT2)], person]$V1
data[i1, WANT2 := NA]     
data
#    person score WANT WANT2
# 1:      1     1    1     1
# 2:      1     2    2     2
# 3:      1     3    3     3
# 4:      1     2    3     2
# 5:      2     2    2     2
# 6:      2     1    1     1
# 7:      2     2    2     2
# 8:      2     3    3     3
# 9:      3     2    2     2
#10:      3     3    3     3
#11:      3     1    3     1
#12:      3     4    4     4
#13:      4     1    1     1
#14:      4     4    4     4
#15:      4     3   NA    NA
```

---

Or create an index where the value 4 is duplicated

```
setDT(data)[, ind := NA^(duplicated(cumsum(score == 4)) & 
         shift(score) == 4), person]
```

then get the cumulative max of 'score' by person while specifying the `i` to select rows where score is greater than or equal to 4

```
data[score >=3, WANT2 := cummax(score), person]
```

and replace the `NA` elements with the 'score' using `pmax` while making sure that duplicated 4 is `NA` (using the 'ind')

```
data[, WANT2 := pmax(score, WANT2, na.rm = TRUE) * ind]
```